# How can I list all updates on a Windows server including superseded ones?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I've run into an issue on an audit. I need to prove that updates are being installed monthly.
The trouble is, all the various options for displaying installed updates ignore superseded updates.
This means that today (1st March 2024) no updates are listed that were installed in January, because they have all been superseded by February's updates.

I have tried:

- Get-hotfix wmic qfe
- Get-WmiObject
- Win32_QuickfixEngineering  Control
  Panel > Programs and Features > Installed Updates
- WSUS Computer
  report

They all ignore superseded updates.
Does anyone know of a way to report a full list of all updates that have been installed on a server?

Comment: Nope. ALL Windows patches/updates are superseded except for the current month. That was implemented over 10 years ago to prevent busy work like this because someone doesn't understand Windows patching 101.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the question before being sarcy.  I'm well aware that patches get superseded each month.  What I want is a report showing all updates that have been installed regardless of whether they were later superseded.  Windows has this data. It is in the update history under settings. I just can't find a way to output it.